# How to create a bean from a fully-qualified class name specified in external configuration? (Spring)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration

I'm using Spring Boot and have an external configuration file called `application.yml`.

In this file, suppose I have a property `foo` that takes a fully-qualified class name as value.

Using Java configuration, what is the typical way to create a bean of the type specified by the `foo` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that `foo` is implementing some known interface. Otherwise, it is kind of pointless to create a bean of an unknown Type.

Something like:

```
@Configuration
public class FooConfiguration {

  @Value("foo.class-name") // ref to the key used in you application.yml
  private String fooClassName;

  @Bean
  public FooInterface fooBean(){
    FooInterface fooImpl = Class.forName(fooClassName).newInstance(); // concreet implemetation
    return fooImpl;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Wasn't sure if there was some Spring-specific way other than reflection. Yes, `foo` is implementing some known interface.

Comment: If there is a limited number of known implementations then you could use `@ConditionalOnProperty` and avoid reflection.

Comment: Thank you Dirk. I'll have a look at that.